# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -4

Tags: java

I have this simple Java code which gives the following error:
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -4

the code is:

```
String date = "14000101";
String repayDate = date.substring(0, 4)+"-"+date.substring(5, 2)+"-"+date.substring(6, 2);
```

the length of the string is 8 and yet it gives an error starting form the second part.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: read javadoc for java.lang.String.substring(int, int)

Comment: According the doc; Throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if beginIndex or endIndex are negative, if endIndex is greater than length(), or if beginIndex is greater than startIndex

Comment: Second argument of substring method is not the legnth but the end position of the substring. So, you want something like:date.substring(0, 4)+"-"+date.substring(5, 7)+"-"+date.substring(6, 8);

Comment: The really interesting question here: why do we have such great existing question for ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, and NPE, ... but not for this stuff?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517711/getting-java-lang-stringindexoutofboundsexception-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`date.substring(5, 2)` should be `date.substring(5, 7)` and `date.substring(6, 2)` should be `date.substring(6, 8)`.

The second argument is the index of the character following the last character of the desired sub-string.

Answer (score 1):

You are givin negative values:

[Api][1]
    [1]: http://www.w3api.com/wiki/Java:String.substring()

```
public String substring(int beginIndex)
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

If you put beginIndex lower that endIndex, crash.

You should do something like this:

```
String repayDate = date.substring(0, 4)+"-"+date.substring(5, 7)+"-"+date.substring(6, 8);
```

Try it! 
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

In your code, endIndex is lesser than beginIndex. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

> ```
> beginIndex - the beginning index, inclusive.
> endIndex - the ending index, exclusive.
>
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or 
> endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or 
> beginIndex is larger than endIndex.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

java is kind of different to python....

this is invalid as reflected in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)

```
 substring(5, 2)
```

the second integer must be bigger than the first one

```
if (endIndex > value.length) {
      throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
}
```

if you mean to get 2 chars after the first parameter then do something like

```
substring(5, 5 + 2);
```

or even better:

```
int beginIndex = 5;
String dateB = date.substring(beginIndex, beginIndex + 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

read javadoc for java.lang.String.substring(int, int)

```
String date = "14000101";
    String repayDate = date.substring(0, 4)+"-"+date.substring(4, 6)+"-"+date.substring(6, 8);
    System.out.println(repayDate);
```